# Fan speed control using PWM inside BASH script

Tags: pwm, bash

Is there a way to run some kind of PWM for fan speed control inside bash script?

Here is my current script

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rpipwm
# Required-Start:    $local_fs 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: rpipwm
### END INIT INFO

    a="echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport;"
    a=$a"echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/export;"
    a=$a"echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/direction"
    eval $a
#start loop script
while true;
do
    #Read temp
    cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
    cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
    temp=$cpuTemp1

    a=""

    #If temperature is equal or lower than 39, the fan will stop spinning
    if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp <= 39") == 1 ]] ;
    then
        a=$a"echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value"
    fi
    #If temperature is between 40 and 42.99, the fan will start with 2 second burst and 1 second sleep
    if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 40 && $temp <= 43") == 1 ]] ;
    then
        a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 2; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 1 "
    fi
    #If temperature is between 44 and 48.99, the fan will start with 5 second burst and 1 second sleep
    if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp > 44 && $temp <= 49") == 1 ]] ;
    then
        a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 5; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 1" 
    fi
    #If temperature is equal or higher than 50, the fan will start spinning constantly
    if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 50") == 1 ]] ;
    then
        a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value" 
    fi

    eval $a

    sleep 0.1
done
```

I want to avoid sleep or somehow simulate PWM to my fan have real speed control instand of ON/OFF in defined intervals.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What PWM are you trying to generate?  We need to know the frequency and the number of steps between on and off.

Comment: I need to experiment that yet. Currently script just on/off fan in certein time my fan what is not good for me.

Comment: I don't see how to help without knowing the sort of PWM you need to control the fan.

Comment: Let's try something like this: 100Hz - 50% duty cycle. On this example I can build other things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd use one of the many libraries and/or daemons available to you to do the PWM.

Have a look at [servoblaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster) and its clones which provide daemons to provide dedicated PWM.

Or perhaps have a look at the PWM features provided by [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) with the bundled gpio utility.

Another alternative is my [pigpio daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) and the [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) utility which provides multiple ways of generating PWM.

All of these can be called by a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

BASH script for PWM

```
function gpiopwm() {
    sleep_low=$(awk -v freq="$2" -v duty="$3"  'BEGIN{print (1/freq)*((100-duty)/100)}')
    sleep_high=$(awk -v freq="$2" -v duty="$3"  'BEGIN{print (1/freq)*((100-(100-duty))/100)}')
    var_count=0
    repeat=1000
    while [ $var_count -lt $repeat ]
    do
        echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$1/value
        sleep $sleep_high
        echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$1/value
        let var_count=var_count+1
        if [ $var_count -le $repeat ]
    then
        sleep $sleep_low
    fi
        done
}
```

Based on the frequency & duty cycle parameter, this function 'on' and 'off' the GPIO in different wavelength

Full script for PWM based on CPU temperature using BASH is @ https://github.com/mohdismailj/fancontrol

Refer my [implementation](https://youtu.be/enco-fARksk)

Comment: Could you please provide a full description of **all** of the code here. Also, please stop linking to the same YouTube video without disclosing your affiliation.

Comment: This is cool code